# UML Eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse, installation, eclipse-3.6, tool-uml

I need to build a class diagram and I want to use UML 2 for Eclipse Helios but I can't find how to install it. Please help!

Comment: Did the solution provided below helped you ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help you ..

[Creating UML 2 diagrams with Eclipse UML2 Tools - Tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=432)

[Installation of UML 2 in Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/uml2/docs/articles/Getting_Started_with_UML2/article.html)

[How to install UML2-Tools on Helios](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/171354/549367/)